# Setting a value for when value isn't present

Tags: django

Using `request.POST.get` you can do this:

```
token = request.POST.get('token', False)
```

Is there a way to do the same thing using

```
request.data['token']
```

Comment: Give an example of the data you are trying to access. What's wrong with the first approach that you mentioned? Is it that you don't want to use the `.get()` notation or that the data is nested?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out.

Axios was serializing the object to JSON by default while I needed to send the data in the `application/x-www-form-urlencoded' format. I used the 'qs' library to achieve this.

```
var qs = require('qs');

axios.post('/foo', qs.stringify({ 'bar': 123 });
```

Thought it was a Django issue but it was actually Axios.

Answer (score -1):

The HttpRequest object doesn't have a 'data' attribute, but depending on what you are looking for there are other attributes, such as 'body', 'FILES', 'META'.  Full details in the documentation:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/request-response/